# Problema con npm run build con react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment, build

Estoy intentando hacer un deployment de una simple React app, creada con create-react-app. 
La cuestión es que lo NO funciona es el npm run build. Cuando ejecuta eso la consola me dice el siguiente error.

"Failed to compile.

EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/macbook/Desktop/UTN/REACT JS/Trabajos practicos/Unidad 3 y TP final Modulo1/miprimeraapp/build/static/css'

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! miprimeraapp@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the miprimeraapp@0.1.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/macbook/.npm/_logs/2020-03-21T08_19_51_114Z-debug.log "

El npm start funciona correctamente. Yo puedo ver la aplicación en mi localhost pero problema parece ser el npm run build. 
Cosas que he probado:

- Instalar las versiones mas recientes de npm y node
- eliminar el package json manualmente y reinstalar npm
- eliminar el caché de npm

Alguna idea? 
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: revisa los permisos y el dueño de las carpetas donde está tu código local. Se supone que en cada build la carpeta donde va ese build re limpia antes de generar el nuevo contenido. Si el directorio `miprimeraapp` no es de tu mismo usuario o si la carpeta build existe (o alguna de sus subcarpetas) y es de `root` por ejemplo

Comment: Gracias. Ya lo solucione!

Comment: Y que era? Cuéntanos porque puede ayudar a alguien

Comment: Si. Lo solucione con este hilo de stack overflow en inglés. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780664/could-not-find-plugin-proposal-numeric-separator